# stop 12am from appearing as 12:00 AM apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to display value as 12am rather than 12:00 AM. In my function I have tbtimes to display 12am, however when I run the function google sheets displays the cell as 12:00 AM. Is there a way to fix this?

```html
tbtimes[0] =  " 12am";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix the value with quote: `'`. This tells Google sheets that the data is not to be interpreted.

```
tbtimes[0] =  "' 12am";
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange("A1").setNumberFormat("@").setValue(" 12am");
```

- By `setNumberFormat("@")`, a value of  `12am` is put into a cell as a string.

#### Sample script 2:

From your following reply,

> I have tbtime in an array and then to set the value I'm using tbsheet.getRange("B41:C42").setValue(tbtimes[0]);. I tried adding in setNumberFormat("@") before set value() and the time still displayed as 12:00 am on my google sheet.

In this case, it seems that it is required to set the value using `setValues` as follows.

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const range = sheet.getRange("B41:C42");
const values = range.getValues().map(r => r.map(_ => " 12am"));
range.setNumberFormat("@").setValues(values);
```

#### Note:

- As additional information, I think that when `setNumberFormat("@")` is changed to `setNumberFormat('ha/p"m"')`, the inserted values can be used as the date object.

#### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: I have tbtime in an array and then to set the value I'm using tbsheet.getRange("B41:C42").setValue(tbtimes[0]);.  I tried adding in setNumberFormat("@") before setvalue() and the time still displayed as 12:00 AM on my google sheet.